# gtag.js Producing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am updating my site to use Google Tag Manager for the GA4 change over and when using the following code provided by Google I get an Unexpected token error:

```js
 <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TAG_ID"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'TAG_ID');
  </script>
```

The error is the following:

> gtag.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I have double-checked the formatting and for any special characters. Not seeing anything on my end. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: The reason you're getting the error here is that the snippet includes HTML in the JavaScript area; remove the comment and `<script>` `</script>` tags in a snippet if you place it in the JavaScript box.

Comment: The script you have written is gtag and not a GTM, if you want to switch to GTM you do not need the gtag script.
anyway, make sure you have written this script as the first script in your head tag and finally if still exists the error, please share a screen shot of your head tag where it is written this script